# Panoromic image construction

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to construct a panoromic view from different images.
Initially I tried to stitch two images as part of panoromic construction.
The two input images I am trying to stitch are:
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

I used ORB feature descriptor to find features in the image,then I found out Homography matrix between these two images.
My code is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

Mat img1 = imread(argv[1],1);
Mat img2 = imread(argv[2],1);
//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using orb Detector
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp2,kp1;

// Default parameters of ORB
int nfeatures=500;
float scaleFactor=1.2f;
int nlevels=8;
int edgeThreshold=15; // Changed default (31);
int firstLevel=0;
int WTA_K=2;
int scoreType=ORB::HARRIS_SCORE;
int patchSize=31;
int fastThreshold=20;

Ptr<ORB> detector = ORB::create(
        nfeatures,
        scaleFactor,
        nlevels,
        edgeThreshold,
        firstLevel,
        WTA_K,
        scoreType,
        patchSize,
        fastThreshold );
Mat descriptors_img1, descriptors_img2;


//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
detector->detect(img1, kp1,descriptors_img1);
detector->detect(img2, kp2,descriptors_img2);


Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = ORB::create();
extractor->compute(img1, kp1, descriptors_img1 );
extractor->compute(img2, kp2, descriptors_img2 );
//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
if ( descriptors_img1.empty() )
    cvError(0,"MatchFinder","1st descriptor empty",__FILE__,__LINE__);
if ( descriptors_img2.empty() )
    cvError(0,"MatchFinder","2nd descriptor empty",__FILE__,__LINE__);
descriptors_img1.convertTo(descriptors_img1, CV_32F);
descriptors_img2.convertTo(descriptors_img2, CV_32F);
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors_img1,descriptors_img2,matches);
double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_img1.rows; i++ )
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist )
        min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist )
        max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_img1.rows; i++ )
{
    if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
    {
        good_matches.push_back( matches[i]);
    }
}
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good_matches,img_matches,Scalar::all(-1),
        Scalar::all(-1),vector<char>(),DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
std::vector<Point2f> obj;
std::vector<Point2f> scene;
for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
{
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back( kp1[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( kp2[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
}

Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
```

After wards some people told me to include the following code

```
cv::Mat result;

warpPerspective( img1, result, H, cv::Size( img1.cols+img2.cols, img1.rows) );
cv::Mat half(result, cv::Rect(0, 0, img2.cols, img2.rows) );
img2.copyTo(half);
imshow("result",result);
```

The result I got is
[image: result]

I also tried using inbuilt opencv stitch function. And I got the result
[image: result with inbuilt stitch function]

I am trying to implement stitch function so I dont want to use inbuilt opencv stitch function.
Can any one tell me where I went wrong and correct my code.Thanks in advance

Comment: can you display and save/post "result" directly after warping?

Comment: did you verify that the matching makes sense (function drawMatches or sth.)? Not 100% sure because I didn't work with ORB yet, but I guess it doesn't make sense to convert a binary descriptor zo float for matching (probably using euclidean distance afterwards)?!? Probably you should use HAMMIMG distance for matching.

Comment: instead of converting the descriptors to float, use FlannBasedMatcher matcher(new flann::LshIndexParams(20, 10, 2)); to create a matcher using hamming distance as metric, presented here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5937 maybe you'll have to tune the params for your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image stitching includes the following steps:

1. Feature finding
2. Find camera parameters
3. Warping
4. Exposure compensation
5. Seam Finding
6. Blending

You have to do all these steps in order to get the perfect result.
In your code you have only done the first part, that is feature finding.

You can find a detailed explanation on how image stitching works in [Learn OpenCV](http://www.equal10.com/pdf/Learning%20Image%20Processing%20with%20OpenCV.pdf)

Also I have the code on [Github](https://github.com/Poirot1729/OpenCV/tree/master/Panorama)

Hope this helps.